# linux bash - can I create a shortcut (similar to windows) instead of a symbolic link?

Tags: linux, bash, shortcuts, symbolic-link

so lets say I start here:

`/home/user1/$`

I want to make a shortcut to `/tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here`

Normally I would make a sym link:

`/home/user1/$ ln -s /tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here here`

Then I can do:

```
/home/user1/$ cd here
/home/user1/here$
```

But in this case I want the result to be:

```
/home/user1/$ cd here
/tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here$   <--- path is now explicitly correct
```

and not:

```
/home/user1/$ cd here
/home/user1/here$            <--- path is via sym link
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `set -P`:

```
/home/user1/$ set -P
/home/user1/$ cd here
/tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here$   <--- path is now explicitly correct
```

(undo with `set +P`).

---

Or force this behavior when invoking `cd`:

```
/home/user1/$ cd -P here
/tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here$   <--- path is now explicitly correct
```

---

Or correct your working directory after you `cd` normally:

```
/home/user1/$ cd here
/home/user1/here$ cd `pwd -P`
/tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here$   <--- path is now explicitly correct
```

---

**Or modify your `cd`, so when it's given a *file*, it reads destination from it and acts as you want**:

```
cd(){ if [ -f "$1" ]; then command cd "`cat "$1"`"; else command cd "$@"; fi }
```

Now:

```
/home/user1/$ echo "/tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here" > there
/home/user1/$ cd there
/tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here$   <--- path is now explicitly correct
```

This is a proof of concept. Adjust it to your needs. Some logic to reject binary or large files (given by mistake) may be the first sane adjustment.

Comment: Actually the `set -P` or `cd -P` commands look like really good options I didn't know about those, thanks : )

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a shortcut for "cd" command you can create an alias :

```
alias cd_here='cd /tmp/subdir1/subdir2/here'
```

Also you can do a `mount -o bind /dir/source /dir/dest`

But the one you will see into the prompt will always be (ln way, mount way ) the /dir/dest. In other words the source directory will be mounted into the destination, so it will become transparent (it's the goal on linux) for the end user that the target directory will host the content of the source directory.

Comment: Creating alias can be a workaround (not the solution though) but Why to use mount ?