# what is bash command `command` used for and what is it when it appears in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

when I was writing a shell script, I happen to know `command` is a reserved word. Then I noticed `command`  is also a bash command.

- `command ls` gives the same result as `ls`.
- `command ls | grep xxx` gives the same result as without it.

Then I wonder what is it used for when it is a bash command. And what is it used for when it is in shell script. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`command foo` will run the `foo` command even if there is a `foo` shell function defined. This behavior is [required by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html).

It allows you to call the `foo` command inside the `foo` function. Without `command foo` the function (when invoked) would call itself and create a circular reference.

Well, sometimes you can call the `foo` executable by its full path to suppress the shell function lookup (cumbersome and not portable, still *some kind* of workaround), but in some cases you can't. E.g. in [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1297011/432690) (near the end) I redefine `cd` and `command cd` is a must, because [even if there is a `cd` executable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/50058/108618) which full path I could use, it wouldn't change the directory. Using `command` is *the right way* to deal with this.

Also note `command foo` will not trigger a `foo` alias (if any). You used `ls` as an example. At least few common Linux distros alias `ls` to `ls --color=auto` by default. In this case `ls` and `command ls` may give different results (i.e. colored or not). POSIX (or any other) definition of `command` doesn't need to mention aliases because `bar foo` doesn't trigger `foo` alias (if any) in the first place (with few possible exceptions regarding `bar`, but `command` is not one of them).

Whether you use `command foo` in an interactive shell session or in a shell script may matter to `foo`, but not to the `command` builtin itself.